ofstream causing memory increase
This is a mini test. The memory used by this C++ program increases from 1KB to 10MB while writing a string to a file. It seems that ofstream didn't release its memory after append.
In theory, std::ofstream should write data directly to a file instead of writing to memory. However, the program's memory usage may continue to increase.
Is this normal?
int main() {
    std::string test = "this is a test string xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 1000; i++) {
        std::ofstream oss("/opt/agent/log/log.txt", std::iostream::app);
        if (oss.is_open()) {
            oss << test;
            oss.close();
        }
        usleep(1 * 1000);
    }
    return 0;
}

my program produces larger log so this is not acceptable.
More info:

the memory is measured by register the program as a service, so we can get the status using systemctl status xxx.service


How are you measuring memory usage? It's normal for a program to show higher apparent memory usage after running some code. Does the memory usage continue to increase after running your program for longer?

"In theory, std::ofstream should write data directly to a file instead of writing to memory." -- I am not familiar with this theory. Do you have a source for it? I am familiar with the theory that streams may buffer data in memory.

That's not due to buffering. The ofstream is getting closed in each iteration (close() call is redundant by the way). If memory is not getting released then it's a leak, a bug. However I can't reproduce it.

std::ofstream oss is closed and it releases resources after every iteration. There are no leaks in your program, if that's what concerns you. Then it's up to the operating system how much memory it decides to give to your process. How do  measure it?

'It seems that ofstream didn't release its memory after append.'. No you've provided no evidence for that. First thing you need to do is state how you are measuring memory usage. A lot of beginners don't understand how memory usage works, you may or may not be one of them, but we won't know until you state precisely what you are measuring.

the memory is measured by register the program as a service, so we can get the status using systemctl status xxx.service

Just because your program frees or deletes memory does not mean it is instantly given back to the OS. Your memory manager typically holds on to a chunk of memory so it can satisfy future memory allocations quicker.

@GeoffreyGeng OK that measures the amount of memory that the O/S has allocated to the service. When C++ program releases memory it gets returned to the program (so that future allocations by the program can reuse the released memory). It does not get returned to the O/S. So a C++ program can release memory correctly but from the O/S point of view the memory usage does not drop. This is the misunderstanding that many beginners have about memory usage.

I will believe this is a memory leak when you can make it OOM crash or you can show that each loop increases memory usage linearly.

If you run your service in a loop for a couple of minutes, and measure your systemctl status xxx.service every second, I'm pretty sure you will notice that it saturates at some arbitrary value.

What you said makes sense. Will  ostream continuously alloc and free memory without return it to OS? My program produce so large  and so many log, the log file increase form 20MB to 400MB after a day and it continuously increases.

I will run a langer time for more detail. Is there a path to void this?

Another question is why fstream internal function did not alloc the same memory?
